# Django, How to get object instance(id) before creating it in form_valid function of generics view?

Tags: python, django, model, signals

When i creating Post model object i need to get it ID instantly and create a second model User_permission , how in this case can i pass to post variable the ID data of newly created post

```
  class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
        model = Post
        form_class = PostForm

        def form_valid(self, form): 
                obj = User_permission.objects.create(post=post)
                obj.save()
            return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: You can't have the object.id if you let database auto-generate one. But you can spcify an id when save the data.

Answer (score 2):

Objects do not have `id`s until saved. You would need something like

```
    def form_valid(self, form): 
            response = super().form_valid(form) # saves object
            obj = User_permission.objects.create(post=self.object)
            obj.save()
            return response
```

[This example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#ajax-example) in the documentation shows use of self.object

Comment: You don't need to save the object after you create it, the creation saves it automatically.